# How to disable Remote Admin Console for Websphere 6.1

Tags: remote-access, websphere

Is it possible to disable the admin console in IBM websphere 6.1 on Windows 2003 for non-local users? If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just change the "admin_host" host alias to not specify the wildcard for the hostname/interface.  Otherwise, you can edit the web container transport chains (via the server itself) to not listen on * but on 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your security configuration store. If you are using local store for authentication than yes. In case of LDAP I do not think so. on how to do it look at the

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tsec_csec2.html